# Logo should appear on the strip

Tags: html, css

I am beginner in this field.I want the logo(image used) to appear on the strip itself but when I use this code it appears below that strip.Basically, I want a strip with background colour black and a heading/title in the centre with a logo at the rightmost corner of that coloured strip.
Here's my code:-

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>MIT PULSE-Home</title>
    <style>
        .topbar{
         
            color:white;
            background-color:black;
            height:125px;
            width=100%;
            text-align: cente
            border-bottom:solid 2px red;
            
        }
        #Shift{
            margin-top:10px;
            font-size:100px;
        }
       
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
    
    
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
      <div class="topbar">
          <p align="center" style="font-size:100px">MIT Pulse</p>
          <img  src="logo.jpg" align="right" height="75">
        
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you notice the "width=100%;" (which should be width: 100%;" and the "text-align: cente" (which should be "text-align: center;") ?

Comment: avoid using inline css / js - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code, use external stylesheets / .js files :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? I corrected a few mistakes in your CSS code, added `position: relative;` to your class `.topbar` and created a new class `.logo` which I added to the `<img>`-Tag.

Also, keep in mind the comment from [ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7611062/thisguyhastwothumbs), you shouldn't use inline CSS

For further reading on relative/absolute positioning, I recommend the MDN articles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>MIT PULSE-Home</title>
    <style>
        .topbar{
         
            color:white;
            background-color:black;
            height:125px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom:solid 2px red;

            /* Position the element relative */
            position: relative;
            
        }
        #Shift{
            margin-top:10px;
            font-size:100px;
        }

        .logo {
           /* Absolute position for this element */
           position: absolute;

           /* Distance from the right side */
           right: 0;

           /* Center image vertically */
           top: 50%;
           transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
       
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
    
    
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
      <div class="topbar">
          <p align="center" style="font-size:100px">MIT Pulse</p>
          <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" align="right" height="75">
        
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes !Thanks a lot ! I am not aware of the transform, so I need to read on that a bit.Thanks a lot man. I have been googling my query for past hour-got many results but something or the other went wrong.

Comment: Cool, you can accept it as the correct answer then :) or the other solution, if that one works better, just make sure you mark an answer as the correct one

Comment: I will surely give those articles a read and will no longer use inline css.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The logo is appearing below the title because `<p>` is a block-level element -- that is, it will force the next element to appear on the next line.

By making the title a `span` with `inline-block` display you can achieve something like this snippet. (As with other replies I've fixed some typos and removed unused CSS. Also, I second the comment regarding inline CSS.)

EDIT: more on layouts & block vs. inline at this [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure)

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>MIT PULSE-Home</title>
        <style>
            .topbar{
             
                color:white;
                background-color:black;
                height:125px;
                width:100%;
                text-align: center;
                border-bottom:solid 2px red;
                
            }
    
            .right {
                float: right;
            }
    
            .title {
                font-size: 100px;
                display:inline-block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
           
            body{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
        
        
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class="topbar">
              <span class="title">MIT Pulse</span>
              <img  src="logo.jpg" class="right" height="75" >
            
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This also works well.Thank you.In the online course I am doing, I wasn't made aware about block level elements and thanks for the link for tutorials.I will definitely refer those.

Comment: Thanks -- if it works could you give it an upvote? Ta.